# Logging only the message using winston

Tags: node.js, express, winston

I am using winston logger in my node app and i want to log my custom message to the log file.

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            level: 'info',
            filename: '/tmp/test.log',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            maxsize: 20971520 //20MB
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});
```

I only need to log message in the log, i dont need to log level and timestamp in the log file. Current logged sample is as below.

```
{"level":"info","message":"sample entry to log","timestamp":"2015-12-11T09:43:50.507Z"}
```

My intention is to get entry in the log file as below

```
sample entry to log
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Winston 3:

```
import winston from 'winston';

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({
      format: winston.format.printf(log => log.message),
    })
  ]
});

logger.info('eat my shorts');
```

Answer (score 0):

On Winston 2.x
If you want to print only the message, you can achieve this by setting:

```
json: false,
timestamp: false,
showLevel: false
```

Full Logger example:

```
let logger = new Logger({
  transports: [
    new (transports.File)({
      name: 'info-file',
      filename: 'filelog-info.log',
      json: false,
      timestamp: false,
      showLevel: false
    })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});
logger.log('info', 'eat my shorts');
```

gives in filelog-info.log: `eat my shorts`

FYI: filters and rewriters didn't help here

Comment: with the winston-daily-rotate-file@3 (for winston@2),  `winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({showLevel:false})` fail to disable show level .  why ?

Comment: no idea.
-> [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone, as did I, finds this question in hopes of making `express-winston` log only message (to the console in my case)

Here is what I did:

```
const winston = require('winston');
const expressWinston = require('express-winston');
const { MESSAGE } = require('triple-beam');

expressWinston.logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            format: simpleformatter()
        })
    ]
});

const simpleformatter = winston.format(info => {
    info[MESSAGE] = info.message;
    return info;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Yep got the one i was looking for

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#filters-and-rewriters

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#custom-log-format

Comment: These links are no longer relevant, and this does not answer the question.  More specificity would be helpful since this answer comes up at the top of a google search.